# Improvements for 'most important theorem in group theory' question

Tags: discussion, re-open

I have not made a re-open request before, and I hope this is the proper way to do it.  If not, I would greatly appreciate some help so I can do it properly.

I would appreciate feedback on how [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476972/theorems-with-the-greatest-impact-on-group-theory-as-a-whole) of mine can be improved enough for it to be re-opened.  I edited it but no one has commented since.  Specifically, could the phrasing be changed from a 'most important' viewpoint to a 'very far-reaching,' 'widely applicable,' or 'theorems that impacted group theory the most' point of view (one or all three, as they are certainly related)?

I will still maintain that the original wording is not bad, as Joseph Gallian and G.A. Miller are willing to rank certain theorems by importance, and I doubt they are alone in this.  However, more than anything I would like to see the question re-opened, as I think it is interesting, and there is some community interest as evidenced by the 4 upvotes and 'favorited' status.

I appreciate the thoughts.  Thanks.

Comment: Although this *is* subjective, I agree with user18921's point that "Understanding the theorems that are considered most important in any field of math is an important step towards understanding that field." Therefore, I believe that your question should be re-opened, and incidentally is fine as it is (although I am sure someone will come up with an improvement).

Comment: Also, the "most important theorem" in finite group theory is going to be pretty elementary (although I am sure someone will mention the [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups)). However, this is not the case in infinite groups. Certainly, every "most important" candidate I can think of is highly non-trivial...So this question is interesting to me :-)

Comment: @Alex I agreed with the arguments put forward, and have cast the final reopening vote. It could be "primarily opinion-based", but as long as answerers try to answer in all seriousness, I think it won't degrade into a poll.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Thank you, I really appreciate that.

Comment: [Told you](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/479440/10513) someone would mention the classification!